# socket io load test using artilary

Tags: socket.io, artillery

```
config:
  target: "http://192.168.2.161:5000"
  phases:
    - duration: 600
      arrivalRate: 5
scenarios:
  - name: "oz_event"
    flow:
      - loop:
          - emit:
              channel: "oz_event"
              data: "hello world!"
              namespace: "oz"
          - think: 1
        count: 50
```

It is my artilary code. When I am run this code then showing **an URL must be specified**

Answer (score 2):

I have resolved this issue using following code

```
config:
  target: "http://192.168.2.161:5000"
  phases:
    - duration: 600
      arrivalRate: 5
scenarios:
  - engine: "socketio"
    flow:
      - emit:
          channel: "oz_event"
          data: 'hello'
          namespace: "oz"
          response:
            channel: "oz_response"
            data: "hello"
```